# Despite of so much assumptions and approximations,why physics work so well?

Tags: everyday-life

I always believe that physics can explain everything happening around us.Our every single action can be defined by physical laws.

Now I m coming to the question(as I have mentioned the laws), the assumptions are the base of physics( I apologise if someone disagree) and still these assumptions work so well in general.

Now,Let's talk like gentleman,**The kinetic theory of gases is completely based on certain assumptions**these assumptions are so helpful in understanding gaseous phenomena.

Whenever I read about gravity I always find an assumption that **assume earth to be a sphere**(actually it is not),but still the effect of rotation of earth on value of **g**,effect of height and depth on **g**(acceleration due to gravity) 
works well.

Edit:After reading the disappointing comments I have tried to compress this question.

These assumptions are basis of physics and are working so well,but still these are assumptions.What make these assumptions work so well in general life?? How these assumptions are made so that they are never failed??

Comment: atleast give your views about the question after downvoting it.

Comment: Maybe you want to read about the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences

Comment: The Earth *is* a sphere to within 3%: this is a perfectly reasonable approximation for many purposes.  People who need more accurate measures use them: there is a whole field of study -- geodesy -- that deals with this subject.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a physics question per-se, but a meta-physics question (in the sense that it is asking a question about the entire field of physics itself and why it "works")

Comment: It is a bad question because you are confusing assumptions and approximations (also called simplifications), and how useful it is to use them. I did not vote you down, but the answers should have differentiated between the two. None of your examples are assumptions (maybe the first one started that way as a simplification, close to an approximation): the first one simplified that they are mostly non interacting, the earth was clearly a simplification (unless you think people didn't see mountains), and the third was completely superceded by quantum mechanics-not the base of science

Comment: To reopen  this question, please focus on one particular part of modern physics that you are uncomfortable with. As written, it is not clear what exactly you want to know.

Comment: This is a thinly disguised rant. I see no reason to reopen this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting many, many assumptions and theories that *do not* work and therefore are chucked away again.

Scientists and researchers set up certain hypothesises and look to find if they can be unverified. Many can and are never heard of again. But when suddenly one hypothesis is not just disproven experimentally, and also not in the next and next and next experiment - and when later on many *other* researchers try to disprove but also can't through many experiments - then we sort of have the feeling that maybe this is actually true.

A law of nature, like Newton's laws and the law of energy conservation etc., are very fundamental assumptions that have shown to always work after centuries and countless trials. It has never been disproven, but also never proven. Just experimentally verified countless times. You pick up a pen and expect it to **fall** when you drop it - not because anyone proved to you that this will happen, but because it **always has done so**. You trust that to also happen next time.

If you would never trust it, you will never get further. The fundamental laws *cannot* be proven 100 %, so that would stop all progress in science. At some point you must accept this as by far most likely the truth.

---

Now one thing is basing physics on law's that cannot be fundamentally proven, but only trusted.

Another thing is *knowing* that you are off but still "assuming" for example a perfectly round Earth. In this case you are not fighting what you don't know, just simplifying what you know. This is a different story, because you can usually calculate accurately (or accurately enough) what the error will be from this assumption. Does that simplification turn out insignificant or close-to-insignificant, then maybe it is worth the ease in work-load or simulation-time etc. to use it.

**Bottom line is:** In physics you only *assume* whats necessary and then you test it to death. But you often *simplify* when that is know/found to be no big deal.

Comment: +1 nice post and very well expressed, it's a pity, and I do appreciate you can't,  just write, "we can only falsify theories" and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

What is an assumption? The definition of an assumption, is a thing that is accepted as true or as certain to happen, without proof. You make an assumption at the beginning of your question, stating that you believe Physics can explain everything happening around us, and that our every action can be defined by physical laws.

The **single greatest** assumption of Physics is that the universe is governed by a strict set of laws. This categorically can't be proven, we take it as fact in order to progress with the discipline. However, what if the universe is governed by laws unfathomable to human minds? It's impossible to say this isn't the case, however much it seems like it isn't.

Physics has assumptions in order for the discipline to progress. If it didn't, we'd be stuck contemplating whether the universe even follows the laws of Physics for millennia.